# Write text on preview window in directshow?

Tags: directshow

I have an application that uses DirectShow to capture video from camera.

It simultaneously save video on disk and show a preview window to user.

I want to add some text to preview window. So i wrote this code:

```
HWND hwnd = FindWindow(NULL, L"ActiveMovie Window");
HDC DeviceContext = GetDC(hwnd);

SelectObject(DeviceContext, (HFONT)GetStockObject(ANSI_FIXED_FONT));
char DebugTextBuffer[64] = { 0 };
sprintf_s(DebugTextBuffer, sizeof(DebugTextBuffer), "This is just a test.");
TextOutA(DeviceContext, 0, 0, DebugTextBuffer, (int)strlen(DebugTextBuffer));
```

But it doesn't show any text.

Edit: The above code however render text on a normal windows properly.

Comment: The code is not the right way to render text neither on normal video nor, especially, on video. Please do a research first, text-on-video with DirectShow was discussed multiple times over 20+ years.

Comment: I found VMR-9 filter. This is an example that uses it:

https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-classic-samples/tree/master/Samples/Win7Samples/multimedia/directshow/vmr9/watermark

But unfortunately i got this error message:
https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-classic-samples/blob/master/Samples/Win7Samples/multimedia/directshow/vmr9/watermark/watermark.cpp#L957

Comment: @RomanR. TBH, i'm a little confused. There are lots of ways that people suggets on the internet. Someone says that use DirectWrite. Someone says that use VMR-9, etc.

I don't know which method is easier and more robust to implement.

Comment: The question in current state is too broad to give good answer (it will exceed the question in size multiple times). The rendering method in code snippet is inappropriate. You need to constrain the question to specify what video renderer you are using, it looks like VMR-9 solution will not work for you (for example).

Comment: @RomanR. This one: `CLSID_VideoRenderer`

Comment: One way you could accomplish is by inserting a suitable filter in your graph just before the video frames are sent to the preview window. As an example, the Video Text Overlay filter from the LEADTOOLS Multimedia toolkit (Which is what I am familiar with since I work for the vendor) can be used to add a text overlay. You can find more details here (https://www.leadtools.com/support/forum/posts/t12299-).